# Potions crafting - homebrew ideas

Tags: dnd-5e, crafting, potions

I am not satisfied entirely with Dnd 5e potions crafting. I am considering to implement simple system, which doesnt take so much time of downtime activity to craft, but needs specific ingredients. For example, lets take Skyrim (elders scrolls) or Witchers game - if you mix that and this so you would have potion of darkvision.

Do you know the system, that has those recipies specified and can be applied to Dnd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Angry GM have made a concept around herbalism that could be reskinned for potion crafting. It lets the character gather ingredients from different biomes and create non-magical products. It is not much, but can be expanded with your own concoctions.

https://theangrygm.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Herbcraft-for-DD.pdf

I have tried to implement this for a player in a campaign. My experience was that the player first loved its own "minigame" of herbalism, but quickly lost interest after a few levels since they got access to better solutions - more and stronger spells.